# A word between boy/girl and man/woman?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, grammatical-gender

My problem is this; the words “boy” and “girl” denote youth (at least to me), while “man” and “woman” denote more of an adult. While I am aware of just adding “young” before “man” or “woman”, but that feels clunky and too formal, so is there some intermediary word between the two?

Comment: **Teen** was a common word in my day, but I hear it less now. A thesaurus might be the place to look.

Comment: How about adolescent?

Comment: Teen/adolescent (and other synonyms) is good, as well as helpful, but there’s one thing it doesn’t have. It lacks specific gender, which is the main thing I’m asking. Still though, that will be helpful for future reference.

Comment: I think this question may be better suited for English SE. Other languages have specific words that you are asking for, but there is no good one-word English translations for them.

Comment: @wetcircuit 'youth' is another slightly outdated term which is male gender-specific, though possibly BrEng. An outdated USEng female-specific term might be 'bobbysoxer' perhaps

Comment: If you want gender-specific terms, can you edit the question to say so, because people are answering with non-gender-specific suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Lad and lass are somewhat appropriate if writing for a UK audience. Generally a lad or lass isn't a small child but somewhere between ten and twenty or so.

Answer (score 1):

***Youngster*** is a good word you could use. It is not too familiar, and it has an affectionate ring to it. It means:

> a young person, usually an older child:
>
> - The scheme is for youngsters between the ages of ten and 16. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/youngster))

***Youth*** is another option, and depending on the context it can be quite poetic. It means:

> a boy or a young man:
>
> - Gangs of youths were throwing stones and bottles at the police.

As for ***[juvenile](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/juvenile)***, it is too technical, usually used in legal writing.